# Why do some Jewish people spill wine on bad neighbor’s door

Tags: passover, plagues-makkos, curse

From what I could have gathered,when reading the ten plagues , some Jewish people gather wine and spill it later on as a way to curse a bad neighbor? What exactly does the curse bring on the house that has been cursed? And is there a way to lift such curse?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I've never heard of such a custom. I suggest you bring a source for this - from where did you come to understand this?

Comment: @Harel13 I've seen the wine gathered and later poured into the neighbour's swimming pool.

Comment: @Adam while odd (and somewhat interesting), can you be certain that this was done in order to seemingly curse the neighbor (perhaps the people involved were drunk...)? Moreover, a source for this supposed tradition would be useful to discern the meaning of the tradition.

Comment: @Harel13 It was clearly and repeatedly (from year to year) stated as being done to convey the curses upon this neighbour, a neighbour who was perceived as intentionally using the pool to display more of the family's skin than comfortable for their ultra-Orthodox neighbours.

Comment: @Adam, forgive me, but there are people missing a few screws everywhere. This doesn't make it a normal or even somewhat normalized tradition, as implied by the questioner.